# Can non-administrators use the Windows AT (Scheduled Task) command?

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-task-scheduler

Is it possible to make a new job in the Windows Task Scheduler using the Command Prompt when a normal user is logged in and they don't have administrator privileges?

Is there a reliable way for all users to make a simple job in the scheduler using the Windows Command Prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, non-admin user accounts can create scheduled tasks, however they will be limited to running under the user’s credentials (i.e., no admin privileges). If you want to create a task that requires admin privileges with a non-admin account, then an admin-account holder must either enter their credentials at the command-line when creating the task or else at the credentials dialog that pops up when the task is executed:

[image]